# When performing a bulk edit on a table, how should changing the filter on the table, affect previous selections?

Tags: tables, filter, selection, edit, bulk

If a user wants to "bulk edit" a table and makes some row selections, then changes the filter during selection, should rows that have been previously selected (but can no longer be seen because they've been excluded by the new filter), still be included in the bulk edit, or not?

Answer (score 0):

They should not, as it would break trust in the application.

If your concern is to make it clear that the size of the records to be acted on has changed, keep a running count visible to the user so they can see the filter has had an impact on how many records are available to modify in the bulk edit.

Answer (score 0):

Minimally, you maintaining context during filtering, pages, etc.

[image]

We spent 30 minutes live working on the problem at Pencil & Paper : https://youtu.be/tLiFfYHP-QY